# Confused about detecting the errors of this code in c programming language?

Tags: c

The code given below is an exercise that our teacher gave to prepare us for exams.
We are supposed to **find the errors** that occur in this code and fully explain them .

```
#define SIZE 10
int start (void a,int k) {
        const int size=10;
        char array[size];
        char string[SIZE];
        mycheck(3,4);
        array[0]=string[0]='A';
        printf("%c %c\n", array[0], string[0]);
        myRec(7); 
}
int mycheck(int a , int b) {
        if (a==0 || b==0 ) {
                return 0;
        }
        else {
                return (a*b);
        }
}
int myRec(int x) {
        if(x==0)
                return 0;
        else
                printf("%d,",x);
        myRec(x--);
}
```

I have found these errors so far:

1.`int start (void a,int k)`

**explanation**: We can't have a variable of type void, because void is an incomplete type

2.`const int size=10;`

**explanation**:we can't use variable to define size of array 
(problem is when I run it in dev-c++ it doesn't show an error so I'm not sure about this)

3.`mycheck(3,4);`

**explanation**: prototype of function mycheck() is not declared, so the function mycheck is not visible to the compiler while going through start() function

4.A friend told me that there is an error in function `myRec` because of this statement `myRec(x--);`

(I don't really get why is this an error and how you can I explain it?)

5.`Main()` function doesn't exist.
I'm not sure about this but if i run the code (in dev-c++) without main function I get a compilation error

**I'm not sure if the errors that I pointed out are 100% right or if I missed an error or if I explained them correctly.**

**Please correct me if any of the above is wrong!**

Comment: 4. The recursion `myRec(x--);` is passing `x` so the termination condition will never be met unless the function was called with `myRec(0);`. Also, not all control paths of this function return a value.

Comment: 2. This hasn't been true since the C99 version of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

> a friend told me that there is an error in function myRec cuz of this
>   statement myRec(x--);

It will lead to **stackoverflow**. Due to post-decrement, the actual argument passed to function `myRec()`, never decreases and therefore the condition:

```
 if(x==0)
    return 0;
```

will never become true. Regarding your rest of the errors, it depends on the compiler version being used:

For example **C99**, you are allowed to have variable size arrays like this:

```
const int size=10;
char array[size];
char string[SIZE];
```

but pre **C99**, you would have to use malloc or calloc. For your functions used without prototype, most compilers would generate a warning and not error and also due to no `#include<stdio.h>` statement, your `printf` would also lead to a warning.i Again, lot of these things are compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.int start (void a,int k)
>
> explanation: We can't have a variable of type void ,because void is an
>   incomplete type

Correct.

> 2.const int size=10;
>
> explanation:we can't use variable to define size of array (problem is
>   when i run it in dev-c++ it doesnt show an error?so im not sure about
>   this!)

This is also correct, that `char array[size];`, where `size` is not a compile-time constant, is invalid in C89.  However, in C99 and newer, this is actually valid and would create a [variable-length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).  It is possible that your Dev-C++ IDE is using GCC with the language set to C99 or newer, or has GNU C extensions enabled to enable this feature.

> 3.mycheck(3,4);
>
> explanation: prototype of function mycheck() is not declared.So the
>   function mycheck is not visible to the compiler while going through
>   start() function

Correct.  This can be fixed either by declaring the function's prototype before the `start()` function, or just moving the whole function to the top of the file.  As noted by [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight) in the comments, in C89, this should not actually be a compiler error, since functions are implicitly declared when they are used before any actual declaration as `int ()`, i.e. a function returning `int` with any arguments, which is compatible with the declarations of `mycheck` and `myRec`.  It is however bad practice to rely on this, and implicit function declaration does not work in C99 or newer.

> 4.a friend told me that there is an error in function myRec cuz of this statement myRec(x--);
>
> (I don't really get why is this an error and how you can explain it?)

This function is a recursive function.  This means it calls itself within itself in order to achieve a kind of looping.  However, this function as it is currently written would run forever and cause an infinite loop, and since it is a recursive function, and needs a new stack frame each time it is called, it will most likely end in a stack overflow.

The function is written with this statement:

```
  if(x==0)
    return 0;
```

This is intended to terminate the recursion as soon as `x` reaches 0.  However, this never happens, because of this line of code here:

```
  myRec(x--);
```

In C, postfix `--` and `++` operators evaluate to their original value before the addition or subtraction:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x--;
/* x is now 4; y is now 5 */
```

However, using the prefix version of these operators will evaluate to their new value after adding / subtracting 1:

```
int x = 5;
int y = --x;
/* x is now 4; y is now 4 */
```

This means that on each recursion, the value of `x` never actually changes and so never reaches 0.

So this line of code should actually read:

```
  myRec(--x);
```

Or even just this:

```
  myRec(x - 1);
```

> 5.Main() function doesn't exist ...again im not sure about this but if i run the code (in dev-c++) without main function i get a compilation
>   error

This one could either be right or wrong.  If the program is meant to run on its own, then yes, there should be a `main` function.  It's possible that the function `start` here should actually be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  It is entirely valid however to compile a C file without a `main`, for example when making a library or one individual compilation unit in a bigger program where `main` is defined in another file.

---

Another problem with the program is that `myRec` is used before it is declared, just like your point 3 where `mycheck` is used before it is declared.

One more problem is that the functions `start` and `mycheck` are declared to return `int`, yet they both do not contain a return statement which returns an `int` value.

Other than that, assuming that this is the entire verbatim source of the program, the header `stdio.h` isn't included, yet the function `printf` is being used.  Finally, there's the issue of inconsistent indentation.  This may or may not be something you are being tested for, but it is good practice to indent function bodies, and indentation should be the same number of spaces / tab characters wherever it's used, e.g.:

```
int myRec(int x) {
    if(x==0)
        return 0;
    else
        printf("%d,",x);
    myRec(x--);
}
```

Comment: Item 3 isn't an error in C (but may produce a warning).  And the inferred signature is compatible with the actual signature, so it should even work, too.  If this was a review, I'd also pick up on the unnecessary `if` in `mycheck()`, because a simple `return a*b;` would be exactly identical.

Comment: The use of `printf()` without a prototype in place is more suspect (but still safe if I've understood the rules correctly).

Comment: @TobySpeight In the case of `printf`, from what I can tell it's not quite safe since it's a variadic function, and I believe it is undefined behaviour to use a variadic function when it's declared with unspecified parameters (e.g. `int x()` in C89).  Can't find much of a source for this though besides random comments.

Answer (score 0):

1) Hello friend your Recursive function myRec() will go infinite because it 
   call itself with post detriment value as per **C99** standard it will 
   first call it self then decrements but when it call itself again it have 
   to do the same task to calling self so it will never decrements and new 
   stack is created and none of any stack will clear that recursion so 
   stack will full and you will get segmentation fault because it will go 
   beyond stack size.

2) `printf("%d,",x);`  it should be `printf("%d",x);` and you should include #include  library. 
   I think your another mistake is you are calling your **mycheck()** and you 
   returning multiplication of two integer but you are not catch with any 
   value so that process got west.So while you are returning something you 
   must have to catch it otherwise no need to return it.

3) In this you Program main() function missing. Program execution starts 
   with main() so without it your code is nothing. if you want to execute 
   your code by your own function then you have to do some process but 
   here main() should be present.or instead of `start()` `main()` should 
   be present.

4) you can also allocate any char buffer like this `int j; char array[j=20];`

your code should be like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int mycheck(int a , int b) {
    if (a==0 || b==0 ) {
                 return 0;
    }
    else {
                 return (a*b);
    }

}

int myRec(int x) {
      if(x==0)
                  return 0;
        else
                    printf("%d",x);
          myRec(--x);
            }
void main (int argc, char** argv) {

    const int size=10;
    char array[size];
    char string[SIZE];
    int catch = mycheck(3,4);
    printf("return value:: %d\n",catch);
    array[0]=string[0]='A';
    printf("%c %c\n", array[0], string[0]);
    myRec(7);
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Enjoy.............**